# Searching for a Batman comic where Batman had no dialogue and Robin and Alfred were the primary characters

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

I remember reading a comic around 2005 about a Batman print with Batman having no talking role.

**Plot:** Robin and Alfred try to track down the history/origin of Bat cave. They discover that it was old hideout from the war are. Maybe World War II or some other war.

**Characters:** Only remember Robin (most probably Dick Grayson) and Alfred being there. Batman had a cameo, I guess, but I'm not sure of that.

**Title:** Looks like official DC comics with Batman title.

**Release year:** 90s I guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "Batman print"?

Comment: @Buzz comics having batman's name

Answer (score 5):

This is going to be a partial match, because I can't find an issue that matches both of your points. *[Batman: Shadow of the Bat](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Shadow_of_the_Bat_Vol_1_45)* Volume 1, Issue 45, reveals that the origin of the Batcave is with [Joshua](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Joshua_Wayne_(New_Earth)) and [Solomon Wayne](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Solomon_Wayne_(New_Earth)) in the late 19th century, who operated a section of the Underground Railroad in the aftermath of the United States Civil War. This is also stated to be the origin of the secret passage behind the grandfather clock, which they built.

[image: Batman: Shadow of the Bat, Volume 1, Issue 45 - Joshua Wayne points a chained black man toward the manor on the hill while Batman's silhouette menaces across the sky]

However, the synopsis I've found indicates that Batman is the primary character, with Alfred as a secondary one, and Robin not listed at all. Batman starts researching the manor as the result of the body of Joshua being found in the wine cellar.

Comment: sound quite similar but I a sure the version I am looking for Robin was major part of. It can be a one-off or some parallel universe but it's robin who got to the past of caves